# How to optimize query if it uses Pessimistic Write Lock

Tags: locking, spring-transactions, pessimistic-locking

I have a method that can have 1000 requests per second. I need to pause request until one finishes the method. I used Lock Pessimistic Write but It slows response(time about 10 seconds )
What can do the same task with Pessimistic Write but more faster ?

I added composite index id,status for my query ( @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("FROM Wallet w WHERE w.id=:id AND w.status = 'ACTIVE'")
Optional findActiveWalletForUpdate(UUID id);)
But it slowed the query